# Who is this God in the picture?

Tags: shiva, gods, identification-request

I found the below pic in a Facebook post. I know the middle one is Kartikeya and right end one Lord Ganesha. But who is the God in the picture who is seated on the lap of Lord Shiva at the left end  ?

[image]

Comment: Probably Dharma Shasta (Ayyappa).

Comment: @Lazy Do you have any reference for the same ? If yes, you're welcome to post an answer

Comment: I have no references. It is my hopefully-intelligent guess.

Comment: @LazyLubber, that is Baba Balak nath,he was avatar of Kartikeya

Comment: @Nitin May be you are right. I was only guessing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is Baba Balaknath.**

[image]

**I am enclosing His image**.

[image]

You can read about Him here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidh_Bawa_Balak_Nath